# T-SQL stored procedure - how to make parameter that accepts either integer or text

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure that accepts 3 parameters.

```
@row int
,@column VARCHAR(17)
,@value int
```

I want the `@value` parameter to accept either text or integer because it updates different columns depending on `@column` parameter.

Please advise

Comment: Advice: have **two separate** parameters - one for string, one for int - don't mix - it gets messy very quickly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do this, make two stored procedures with different signatures and names. Then you wont need the `@column` parameter and each stored procedure will be simple and behave consistently.

You'll be trading `IF`s and `CASE`es for stored procedure definitions. The query plans for the procedures will behave consistently so could be reliably cached and you'll write about the same number lines overall.

Stored procedures that do widely different queries based on the parameters passed are a performance problem waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare it as a [`sql_variant`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181071%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

```
@row int,
@column VARCHAR(17),
@value sql_variant
```

But this sounds like a **bad idea**.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare varchar parameter and then pass int and do the cast `cast(@value as int)`
Another way to do this is to declare two parameters `@value_int` and `@value_varchar`

But i agree with @podiluska - it sound like you have some design issues, are you sure that you really need that?